# undefined error exception handling inpl/sql

Tags: exception, plsql, undefined, alter

I am new to pl/sql programing. 
I have an assignment :
"Brewbean’s wants to add a check constraint on the QUANTITY column of the BB_BASKETITEM table. If a shopper enters a quantity value greater than 20 for an item, Brewbean’s wants to display the message “Check Quantity” onscreen. Using a text editor, open the assignment04-06.txt file in the Chapter04 folder. The first statement, ALTER TABLE, must be executed to add the check constraint. The next item is a PL/SQL block containing an INSERT action that tests this check constraint. Add code to this block to trap the check constraint violation and display the message."
I tried,like this-

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
ex_basket exception;
pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_basket, -02290);
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE bb_basketitem
  ADD CONSTRAINT bitems_qty_ck CHECK (quantity < 20);
  INSERT INTO bb_basketitem 
   VALUES (88,8,10.8,21,16,2,3);
exception
when ex_basket then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Check Quantity');
END;
```

I got the error report like this:

> ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
>   return select update while with

Sorry for this cheap question. I would love someone helping on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that SQL and PL/SQL are two different languages. `ALTER TABLE` is a SQL statement, and not PL/SQL. You cannot run static SQL DDL statements inside PL/SQL block. However, PL/SQL easily integrates into SQL with the many features it provides. One of these features is [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm).

Therefore, you need dto change yoru ALTER statement to be something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE bb_basketitem  ADD CONSTRAINT bitems_qty_ck CHECK (quantity < 20);'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be very specifi with your code. The below code will suffice your problem.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  ex_basket EXCEPTION;
  pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_basket, -02290);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE bb_basketitem ADD CONSTRAINT bitems_qty_ck CHECK (quantity < 20);';
  INSERT INTO testab VALUES
    (88
    );
EXCEPTION
WHEN ex_basket THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Check Quantity');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding exception handling, this is something that happens at runtime. However if you have an unrecognised keyword like `ALTER` in your code then it won't even compile in the first place, so it won't run at all. Instead, the whole block is rejected as invalid.

Also, `dbms_output` is not generally a good choice for exception handling, as all it does it put a debug message on the output buffer and allow the block to complete successfully, so that whatever script this is part of will have no idea that anything went wrong. You might consider using [`raise` or `raise_application_error`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00705).